# Prevent UIs interaction in Sparkle

Tags: macos, cocoa, sparkle

I am trying to use Sparkle to update an app (not the current app). I start with something simple which is creating the updater object:

```
var updater = SUUpdater(forBundle: appBundle)
```

The problem I'm having is that that line of code can open UI dialogs if something go wrong. For example:

[image]

I can solve that problem, but my concern is that this code is running on a screensaver and popping a dialog like that blocks it to the point where a hard reboot is the only way to move forward.

Is there a way to prevent Sparkle from ever opening any kind of UI?

Comment: After looking at Sparkle's source code, I would consider this a bug, so I reported it: https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/issues/521 I would still be interested in workarounds if anybody knows of one.